# Maintain table cell removal after refresh without touching the post in the database

Tags: ios, swift

I have a post removal function that works great:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    posts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? { let more = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Report") { action, index in self.posts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade) }; more.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue; return [more] }
```

But when you hit refresh, it reloads the posts that my user reports. I want the refresh action not to show these removed posts. However, I want every other user to still see these posts and make their own judgement, so I do not want these posts removed from the database.

What would you advise doing to the refresh function?

For reference, here is my handleRefresh function:

```
@objc func handleRefresh() {
    print("Refresh!")
    toggleSeeNewPostsButton(hidden: true)

    newPostQuery.queryLimited(toFirst: 20).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        var tempPosts = [Post]()

        let firstPost = self.posts.first
        for child in snapshot.children {
            if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                let data = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                let post = Post.parse(childSnapshot.key, data: data),
                childSnapshot.key != firstPost?.id {
                tempPosts.insert(post, at: 0)
            }
        }
        self.posts.insert(contentsOf: tempPosts, at: 0)
        let newIndexPaths = (0..<tempPosts.count).map { i in
            return IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
        }
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: newIndexPaths, with: .top)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
        self.listenForNewPosts()
      //  return completion(tempPosts)
    })
}
```

Comment: You need to remove it from your datasource as well.

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: Are you sure  posts.remove(at: indexPath.row) removes the item at the given index? I mean you are removing it locally but then again fill the array newPostQuery.queryLimited function.

Comment: It sounds like you need to maintain a "removed posts list" for each user and use this to filter the posts that are fetched

Comment: I agree with @Paulw11. You would need a relationship between users and the posts they have reported (don't want to see). ID, userID, reportedPostID. So the user should only be shown posts that are there in POSTS table but whose ID isn't in reportedPostsTable. I am not sure how you are fetching data, but this 1 way using database or core data.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you are storing the data and on refresh if you are fetching the details via Api or local database. But from your I am sure that you need to maintain a flag value in server database or local database at post level that will indicate if this post is to be shown to the tableview or not. If there are multiple users who should not see this post then you have manage an array of the `UserId`s who are not supposed to see this post at post level entry and when you fetch the details in the application, you can filter the details and show those in the tableview.